# programming windows using VC++ express

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Can I develop full fledged win32 app using VC++ express (i.e access to all the win32 APIs). I do't want to use .net, but if it works with .net then its a bonus. I do have Visual studio DVD but I do not want to install ton of crap just to program in C++.

I just want to use windows APIs for networking, filesystem, threads, etc. I'll most probably use GUI Libraries like TK or WX.

Will Mingw allow me to use all of the Win32 APIs.

Comment: What kinds of programs are you trying to create? That information might lead to better answers.

Comment: "...just to program in C++"  Never heard it expressed in this way before.  Usually the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC++ Express has access to all of the Windows API. It does not come with a framework for GUI development, but you can easily add a third party package such as Qt or wx, or work directly with the API if you prefer.

Comment: How about mingw? does mingw has access to all windows APIs. I know threads in mingw works.

Comment: @NikhilRathod, I believe mingw would have access too. I don't know if this is built in or if it requires the Microsoft SDK. All that is required for Windows API access is the header files and libraries that link to the built-in Windows DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

Under Create New Project there's a "Win32" section with "Win32 Project" listed as one of the options.

So as the Express edition is a fully featured IDE (apart from not supporting plugins) then you should be able to build a "fully fledged win32 app".

Comment: That's what I remember also, no plug-ins, no 64-bit compiler.